# Which xml serialization library is performance oriented?

Tags: java, xml, performance, serialization

What is the best XML serialization library for Java if performance is the deciding factor?

Salient Points of application

- Rest Based API.
- Tomcat Servlet Container
- Requires Java Object to XML Serialization
- No requirement for Deserialization or heavy binding libraries.
- Requires open source libraries.

Current Performance Numbers

- XML generated using StringBuffer append of "<", ">" and the like.

  - Average Response Time = 15 ms.
  - Prone to malformed XML and xml encoding errors.
- XML generated using XStream serialization.

  - Average Response Time = 200 ms.
  - Easy to maintain and annotate.

The other libraries which I've come across such as JiBx, JaxB, Castor or Simple seem to be binding frameworks and seem to have a heavy maintenance overhead.

Are there other high performant alternatives for XML serialization or should I just go ahead and implement toXml() using XMLStreamWriter API using woodstox Stax implementation(which seems to have reports of being the fastest among stable open source libraries for the purpose)?

Answer (score 2):

I seriously doubt XStream is taking 200 ms, unless you are sending a very large object.  Are you sure your VM is warmed up?

I wouldn't use StringBuffer as its thread safe with a lock on every call. Use StringBuilder instead.

The following test prints

```
Took 56 us on average to serialise a Person
```

What ever you are serialising is taking 4000x longer. Either your test is not warmed up or you are sending alot of data.  If the later is the case I suggest sending data in a binary format.

---

```
// based on the example in the two-minute tutorial.
public class XStreamTest {
    public static class Person {
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        private PhoneNumber phone;
        private PhoneNumber fax;

        public Person(String firstname, String lastname, PhoneNumber phone, PhoneNumber fax) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.phone = phone;
            this.fax = fax;
        }
    }

    public static class PhoneNumber {
        private int code;
        private String number;

        public PhoneNumber(int code, String number) {
            this.code = code;
            this.number = number;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.alias("person", Person.class);
        xstream.alias("phonenumber", PhoneNumber.class);

        Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Walnes", new PhoneNumber(123, "1234-456"), new PhoneNumber(123, "9999-999"));

        final int warmup = 10000;
        final int runs = 20000;

        long start = 0;
        for (int i = -warmup; i < runs; i++) {
            if(i == 0) start = System.nanoTime();
            String xml = xstream.toXML(joe);
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Took %,d us on average to serialise a Person%n", time / runs / 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [apache avro](http://avro.apache.org/)